# How to properly localize a cross platform program?

Tags: c++, winapi, localization

I am currently making a game engine that is eventually going to support all platforms. Currently I am working on the Windows support with the Win32 API. Reading the documentation, it suggests that I use wide strings/chars and the Unicode version of API functions so that my application can be localized. But if I use wide versions of everything (`wcout` `wstring` `wchar_t` etc.), I will have to make my entire game engine use those wide types. That also means that when working with other platforms, I will also have to use wide types, or I will have to convert between them.

My idea is that maybe my code will only be compiled with wide string types on Windows and be compiled with normal string types on other platforms perhaps with macro definitions. Is that the best option to do this? And how may I go about doing this?

I also don't really understand how unicode works in c++. If I set my system locale to English, then I will get a compiler warning from MSVC if I have any Chinese characters stored in a normal string type. However now I set my system locale to Chinese and enabled UTF-8 encoding, I get no compiler warnings if I store Unicode characters in normal strings. I also have no idea how unicode works on other platforms. Can somebody explain this for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *perhaps with macro definitions* This is effectively what Microsoft did with `TCHAR` and friends back at the turn of the millennium. I'm not a big fan of the approach, especially now that unicode is supported everywhere. Explaining how to do this "right" is several questions unto itself, and I'll have to leave it to someone else because, to be quite frank, I'm not that  good at it either.

Comment: That said, strongly consider using wide characters end-to-end. It's usually worth it and converting back and forth... isn't.

Comment: @user4581301 I've read online about how you should avoid using `wchar_t` on other platforms. Don't exactly know why, but I guess there are different opinions and methods... I think I will start using `wchar_t` everywhere, because I don't think there will be a problem if I use it in code that compiles on other platforms.

Comment: You can do everything in uft8 and have IO convert back and forth to utf16 for Windows. The reason being the only sane encoding is utf8.

Comment: @PasserBy So I'm guessing the standard string class and the normal char type uses UTF8 and the wchar_t type uses UTF16?

Comment: UTF-8 is one or more bytes and you have to read it to find out just how many bytes you need. You generally count on whatever's rendering the string to understand how to interpret it. `wchar_t`'s problem is it varies in size. You could get 4 bytes to hold a decompressed 32-bit unicode character, but might also get 16 bits. A pain in the neck to port, and if you're dealing in UTF-8 it 16 bits might be too short.

Comment: @PasserBy You've mentioned converting back and forth with IO. How exactly may one do that?

Comment: Reread some of what I said above and spotted an ambiguity that probably lead to the question about `wchar_t`. In addition to `wchar_t` you also get `char32_t` which gives you the joys of a fixed-width wide character that doesn't change size when porting and will hold any encoding we monkey boys have come up with so far.

Comment: The idea being you use utf8 until you absolutely have to use anything else, i.e. IO.